# Angular and spring REST API : NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Tags: angularjs, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, maven-2

I GET `NullPointerException` with status code : 400

I am pushing data into a `JsonObject` and then post it to my back end (Spring ) and get the field using `Json` mapper `(data.get("Field name").asText;`.

I also tried `get(index)` and `data.path` but this return `null`, where as in the debug console It indicates that Json objects were received, what is it that makes these fields to be null?

Is it because this data is not directly from ng-model, or is it because I have pushed it into `json` object using Angular, because I am getting 400 erro code.

MY ANGULAR JS :

```
app.controller("OrderOperationsCtrl", function($scope, $http,$window) {

        $http.get(productURL).then(function(response) {
        $scope.productData = response.data; 

        $scope.newData = [];
        $scope.total = 0.0;
        $scope.sync = function(bool,productData,submit){

        if(bool === true){
         var numberOrdered = 0;
         numberOrdered++;
    $scope.total = $scope.total + productData.price;        
    var newD = $scope.newData.push({
        "numberOrdered":numberOrdered,    
    "customerId":localStorage.getItem('takealot_customer'),
    "id":productData.id,
    "total":$scope.total                              
        }); 
        $scope.sender = $scope.newData;
        console.log(" NewD " + $scope.newData);
        }
        if(submit === true){ 
        $http.put(orderURL,JSON.stringify($scope.sender)).then(function(response){               
    if(response.data)
    console.log("Order created !");         
    },function(response){
    console.log("Error creating Order  !");
    console.log(response.status);               
    });
```

MY SPRING CONTROLLER **UPDATE**

```
public ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody OrderOperations[] operation) throws OrderOperationsNotFoundException, IOException{

       logger.info("recieved json String " + operation);
             services.createOrder(operation);            


            return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK); 


     }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT :

```
Hibernate: select products0_.id as id1_3_, products0_.category as category2_3_, products0_.description as descript3_3_, products0_.name as name4_3_, products0_.price as price5_3_, products0_.quantity as quantity6_3_, products0_.supplier as supplier7_3_ from products products0_
2017-11-03 11:34:41.689  INFO 10504 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] 
c.p.C.OrderOperationsController          : recieved json String 

[{"numberOrdered":1,"customerId":null,"id":1,"total":78.32,"$$hashKey":"object:17"},
{"numberOrdered":1,"customerId":null,"id":2,"total":156.70999999999998,"$$hashKey":"object:19"},
{"numberOrdered":1,"customerId":null,"id":1,"total":235.02999999999997,"$$hashKey":"object:21"}]
```

THanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you dont need to map the json into the OrderOperation Object.
Spring will automatically convert the JSON Object into OrderOperations by passing as Parameter

```
public ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody OrderOperations operation)
```

And i think you get the Nullpointer while you parsing the Data

Comment: @nimu1011 how do I then get the fields data and save them ? do I operation.getTotal()? and service.createOrder(operation); after getting fields? can you show me how to get at least one field without using the mapper I have never used your method before. thanks.

Comment: All the data which you send from the frontend (angular) will be mapped in the POJO Object (OrderOperations). Exactly you said, just call the createOrder(operation) to save it. If you Debug your code, you will see that the OrderOperation has the values.

Comment: And do I loop through operations object like : for(I=0; I <= perations.length(); I++){...//save}

Comment: If you send an array from the frontend. Just put an array in the signature. public ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody OrderOperations[] operation)

Comment: Just debug your code, this is the right solution. If woul be nice if you update your question with change code

Comment: When I pass the operations object in the service.createOrder(operation); I get incompatible types . operation becomes incompatible...and cannot be converted to OrderOperations

Comment: @ mimu1011 I just update the controller method ... however as stated above ... operation object  is incompatible ... when I add square brackets. But how can I debug when there is an error sir?

Comment: @NeoSono Make a breakpoint on the logger.info line. Start your Application Debug As. Go to your Frontend and trigger the Angular method. Now, you are in the Debug session. Hover on operations[] and look which data is in that

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have got a solution. some weeks ago.
- For those who are still struggling to save multiple objects from JSON array
see below ... I hope this helps someone else.

```
 public List<String> createOrder(@RequestBody OrderOperations[] json) throws OrderOperationsNotFoundException, IOException{

            logger.info("recieved json String " + json);            
            List<String> response =  new ArrayList<String>();
            for(OrderOperations op : json){                
            services.createOrder(op); 
            response.add("saved order : " + op.toString());
            }
            return response;                        
     }
```